# JQuery : varying modal content

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I already read bootstrap documentation about How to varying modal form content.
But there's not exist an example about 'How to varying modal form content which have input Type="file" ' because I want to varying that input type = " file " with image value.

is it possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the value of an `input type="file"`. The only way to set the value is for the user to select a file.

You can't populate the input with a value, because of security reasons. That would allow you to automatically upload a file from the users computer without the user's approval.